# Selenium any work around for Facebook Connect IE and Safari

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer, selenium

Just wondering if anyone has encountered similar issues and what their 
workaorunds are if any found.

For solutions, looking for Selenium RC, as Selenium 2 / WebDriver is 
last resort as we're not using WebDriver yet.

It seems Facebook connect and related features can be a pain to 
automate, when they launch popups, particularly with IE and Safari.

Tried the various options for Selenium RC:

- getAllWindowTitles/Names/Ids - returns 1 window only (after popup 
  appears, for IE, no use)
- openWindow('','someName') - doesn't seem to have an effect to get 
  popup name/focus after it appears

IE launches popup fine on click but doesn't have way to find and get 
the popup.

and if you manually open new window (using same URL triggered by 
clicking Facebook button, found by spying via tools like HttpFox, 
etc.), the session from login doesn't transfer from the manual popup 
back to the main window, so no login occurs.

Maybe there's a way to invoke the right javascript and maybe 
XmlHttpRequest calls to pass session from popup (when opened manually) 
back to main window?

Any help appreciated. Thanks.